# Facebook Pixel triggering events via if request

Tags: events, facebook-pixel

I am currently trying to install the facebook pixel and let it trigger events via an if-request. I include my head.php in every page and what I basically want to do is: set up a variable on the page, that I want to keep track of, and ask via if-request for these variable in the facebook pixel code so that the corresponding event can be triggered.
Problem is, my events aren't displayed when I look them up on my facebook ad page. Neither can I select the events under "Define Columns" nor can I see them when I click on "Ad Manager" -> Pixel.

Would be very glad if someone had similar problems and solved it or just knows what to do. Thanks in advance!

Here is how my $pixel variable is given before head.php is included (in PHP):

```
if (($_POST['vorname']!="" AND
$_POST['nachname']!="" AND
$_POST['email']!="" AND
$_POST['telefon']!="" AND
$_POST['agb']!=""))
{
$pixel = "teachersent";
}
else{
$pixel = "teacherrequest";
}
include ("../head.php");
```

Same for the other variables on the other page.

Here is my facebook pixel code with the if requests:

```
 <!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
 n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=    [];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', '1425975630785657'); // Insert your pixel ID here.
fbq('track', 'PageView');

var pixeldata = <?php echo json_encode($pixel, JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>; 

if (pixeldata == "teacherrequest") {
fbq('track', 'teacherrequest', {
value: 20,
});
}
else if (pixeldata == "teachersent") {
fbq('track', 'teachersent', {
value: 1,
});
}
else if (pixeldata == "teamrequest") {
fbq('track', 'teamrequest', {
value: 40,
});
}
else if (pixeldata == "teamsent") {
fbq('track', 'teamsent', {
value: 2,
});
}

</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1425975630785657&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- DO NOT MODIFY -->
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

**EDIT**: Thanks to @Cbroe: Installed Pixel helper and spotted that the pixel is found but none of the events are triggered. In the console I could see that the variable of pixeldata is null, meaning that the php variable $pixel is not correctly passed on. So somehow it gets lost on the way from the part of the page before including head.php to head.php where it should be used.

Comment: Verify that the HTML/JS code your PHP script outputs is what you expect it to be, check console for JS errors. If that doesn’t help already, install the Facebook Pixel Helper Chrome extension (not sure if that is available for other browsers as well), and see what that has to say.

Comment: Hi Cbroe, thanks for the tips, helped me a lot. Installed Pixel helper and spotted that the pixel is found but none of the events are triggered. In the console I could see that the variable of pixeldata is null, meaning that the php variable "pixel" is not correctly passed on and converted to the java script variable.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the `<script> var pixeldata = <?php echo json_encode($pixel, JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>;
</script>` outside of the facebook pixel code and somehow it works now.